# How does the anchor tag (<a>) let you do a stored XSS?

Tags: xss

I was trying to get XSS but and site validate input but when I entered `https://google.com` the site did this:

```
<a href="//google.com">https://www.google.com</a>
```

so I tried to do this:

> javascript:alert(7)

the site did this:

```
<a href="//javascript">:alert(7)</a>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to bypass this filter?

Comment: it's a very clear question and I'm testing the site not trying to damage it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get anywhere in security and finding bugs, bypassing security measures you need to start to get *more* creative and more *experimentative* (if that's even an english word).

In this case:

1. Choose an input.
2. Feed it through the black box.
3. Get the output
4. Make a theory: How does the black box transform my input -> output
5. Choose a different input and repeat until confident that you're theory is correct.
6. Adapt/update/change theory with new information from `(input, output)` pairs.

A possible theory in this case would be that the black box simply replaces `https` with an empty string. How do we verify this: Well... we enter "hihttpsthere" and see if we get "hithere" as output. But it transform `javascript:alert(7)` to `(//javascript,:alert(7))` so maybe it's splitting at `:`? Maybe it tries to parse the protocol of the URL? Use some urlencoded stuff, use non-printable characters, maybe even use a fuzzer? It could even be that their filter makes an XSS impossible.. could be. You'll have to find out.

It's all about trial and error.

> I was trying to get xss but site valdiate input

That's what it's supposed to do anyway. You can't expect that you can do an XSS *everywhere*.

Comment: Thanks for all information it's very useful, i tried to understand what site do and i found out that when i enter `javascript:alert(7)` it won't be in `<a>` tag but when site found `http://anything` or `https://anything` site will display it in `<a>` tag so i did this `https://javascript:alert(5)` it becomes `<a href="https//javascript:alert(5)"` and when i tried to do this `http://javascript:alert(6)` it becomes `//javascript:alert(6)` the problem here with `//` do you have any idea how can i bypass it !? , and Thanks again for your replay